# Webpack code splitting to asynrounously load react components within a library

Tags: reactjs, webpack

We have developed a React component library for internal use. The library uses webpack to bundle everything into a bundle.js. The library is exposed as an NPM module for use by our applications, which so far has been working great.

Recently we added a Grid component that has some very large external dependencies. Even though a few of our applications won't need this component from the library, we decided to include it in the final bundle. This can make a huge difference in bundle size, so I followed Webpack's [code splitting guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) to break out the Grid component using a dynamic import. For our applications that have this library installed as an NPM module, the component library bundle now looks like this in `node_modules`:

```
├── node_modules/                 
│   ├── [our component library]/                 
│   │   ├── Grid.js # Asynchronously loaded Grid component
│   │   ├── bundle.js # Main bundle
│   │   └── ... other files in component library bundle
```

When building the application (also with Webpack), the Grid component doesn't seem to be getting included as its own file in the final bundle. In fact, it doesn't get included at all:

```
├── dist/                 
│   ├── main.js # App bundle
│   ├── vendor.js # Vendor bundle created with CommonChunksPlugin
│   └── ... other files in application bundle but no Grid.js
```

When trying to load a page in the browser that is using the asynchronously loaded Grid component, Webpack returns the following error:

```
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
  at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (bundle.js:757)
```

Essentially, this says the Grid component chunk can't be found. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to code split a React component library like this?

Comment: Why don't you make every component in your internal library separately importable? There is no codesplitting required for this. Webpack will only include in the final bundle what was really imported.

Comment: @trixn When you say "separately importable" do you mean make one entry point for every component in the library? Would I still be able to do `import { Component } from 'component-library'`?

Comment: Can you show your entry point files and webpack config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to take a different route with this. Instead of including the Grid component with the rest of the components we split if off into its own npm module. I still see a use case for dynamically importing react components in a library but we felt this was a better solution to our problem. With this solution, the only real downside is that the application will now need to add 2 npm modules instead of one if it needs to use the Grid component and our standard component library. Since our application does code splitting by route with webpack + dynamic imports, the Grid code only gets bundled into the route that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports both import() and require.ensure syntax for dynamic imports. Both worked well. Check this project of mine for good example https://github.com/croraf/myboiler.

This project also is an example: https://github.com/croraf/nutrients-calculator. But I complicated dynamic import part a bit. Check https://github.com/croraf/nutrients-calculator/blob/master/frontend/src/App.js and https://github.com/croraf/nutrients-calculator/blob/master/frontend/src/routes/util/DynamicRoute.js files.

Comment: We do code splitting by route in our projects too. I'm trying to figure out how an application would be able to recognize a library's component that are asynchronously loaded. If our component library and our application were in the same project this would be a lot easier, but that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

one possible reason is babel transpiled your code from `import("..")` to `require`. check transpiled file to confirm this.
if this is the case and you are using `preset`, you can add this to disable this behavior:

```
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    **"modules": false,**
    "targets": {
      "esmodules": true
    }
  }
],
```